# How can i find all values in array of Docs which are equal or bigger than value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array which has docs like this

```
[{name: "Tom", age: 20}, {name: "Frank", age: 25}, {name: "Susie", age: 29}, {name: "Tina", age: 32}]
```

how can i find all people who for example are less or equal then 30 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()`

```js
const arr = [{name: "Tom", age: 20}, {name: "Frank", age: 25}, {name: "Susie", age: 29}, {name: "Tina", age: 32}];

const res = arr.filter(x => x.age <=30)
console.log(res)
```

If you want the names of the persons only then use `map()` after `filter()`

```js
const arr = [{name: "Tom", age: 20}, {name: "Frank", age: 25}, {name: "Susie", age: 29}, {name: "Tina", age: 32}];

const res = arr.filter(x => x.age <=30).map(x => x.name)
console.log(res)
```

Use `Object.entries` to key a nested with index of element `[index,value]` then use `filter()` on that and at the end `map()` to get only `index`

```js
const arr = [{name: "Tom", age: 20}, {name: "Frank", age: 25}, {name: "Susie", age: 29}, {name: "Tina", age: 32}];

const res = Object.entries(arr).filter(([_,v]) => v.age <=30).map(x => +x[0])
console.log(res)
```

Comment: But how would i get the index of the people in the original array ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let arr =[{name: "Tom", age: 20}, {name: "Frank", age: 25}, {name: "Susie", age: 29}, {name: "Tina", age: 32}];

let result = arr.filter(v => v.age <= 30);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeh `filter` it is - and with some exagaration in readability:

```js
const dox = [{name: "Tom", age: 20}, {name: "Frank", age: 25}, {name: "Susie", age: 29}, {name: "Tina", age: 32}]

const arrayWithPeopleWhoForExampleAreLessOrEqualThen30 = 
dox.filter(peopleWhoForExampleAreLessOrEqualThen30)

function peopleWhoForExampleAreLessOrEqualThen30(doc){
 return doc.age <= 30
}
```